# How to stop redirect and stay on the page to scrape the data (python3, beautifulsoup,urllib)

Tags: python-3.x, redirect, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to scrape the review from a website here: http://movie.douban.com/subject/2303845/comments

And apparently it keeps on redirecting itself back to the main page. I would like to find a way to stop the redirecting and stay on the same page to get the part of html that has div with comment as its class.

Keywords: Python3, Beautifulsoup, urllib

I have read other posts and below is what I have tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

sys.setrecursionlimit(30000)

try:
    import urllib.request as urllib2
    import urllib.request as urllib
except ImportError:
    import urllib2

class NoRedirectHandler(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler):
    def http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):
        infourl = urllib.addinfourl(fp, headers, req.get_full_url())
        infourl.status = code
        infourl.code = code
        return infourl
    http_error_300 = http_error_302
    http_error_301 = http_error_302
    http_error_303 = http_error_302
    http_error_307 = http_error_302

opener = urllib2.build_opener(NoRedirectHandler())
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://movie.douban.com/subject/2303845/comments')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
comments = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'comment'})
print (comments)

if response.code in (300, 301, 302, 303, 307):
    print ('redirect')
```

For some reason, I think it is still not getting the data and I suspects it never stops redirecting to the other page.

Answer (score 0):

add cookie to headers
something like(just check what the actual browser set to the douban):

`headers = {
    "User-Agent": random_user_agent(),
    "Cookie": 'bid="' + "".join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, 11)) + '"; gr_user_id=42bc6859-9086-4933-9f19-8f2fc412c37a; viewed="5312099_10355142_4742942_3223711_26642036_25850008_4727293_10580248_3726306"; _ga=GA1.2.1107723060.1458721162; ll="108288"; ps=y; ue="276502214@qq.com"; dbcl2="48221338:qY8I57pvNs8"; ck=xvAF; ap=1; _pk_ref.100001.4cf6=%5B%22%22%2C%22%22%2C1487574236%2C%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.douban.com%2Faccounts%2Flogin%3Fredir%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fmovie.douban.com%252Fsubject%252F2973543%252F%22%5D; _pk_id.100001.4cf6=ccee4c5d3437a382.1482239227.55.1487574252.1487571075.; _pk_ses.100001.4cf6=*; __utma=30149280.1107723060.1458721162.1487570089.1487574236.345; __utmb=30149280.0.10.1487574236; __utmc=30149280; __utmz=30149280.1487518823.338.100.utmcsr=baidu|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic; __utmv=30149280.4822; __utma=223695111.1107723060.1458721162.1487570089.1487574236.52; __utmb=223695111.0.10.1487574236; __utmc=223695111; __utmz=223695111.1487298209.35.8.utmcsr=douban.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/accounts/login; push_noty_num=0; push_doumail_num=0; _vwo_uuid_v2=2D161B768A99F5F485C8FFD318CE8704|b630fad39ce1f3cbdb2e7e44cc9411ca'
    }
    req = urllib.request.Request(
        url,
        data = None,
        headers = headers
    )`

Answer (score -1):

To avoid the redirect change your url to:

```
http://movie.douban.com/subject/2303845/?from=showing/comments
```

from

```
http://movie.douban.com/subject/2303845/comments
```

I changed this line in your code and got an array with 4 `<div class="comment">` 
entries

You can also print out the comments with:

```
for comment in comments:
     print(comment.get_text())
```

Comment: So http://movie.douban.com/subject/2303845/?from=showing/comments actually takes you back to the main movie page. And those four div come from the comments on the main movie page instead of the actually comment listings page at http://movie.douban.com/subject/2303845/comments. :(

Comment: I have to take you at your word since I can't read that language, but http://movie.douban.com/subject/1866473/?from=showing/comments gives me different comments, so in my code when I change the number the output is different so I gather it isn't showing the main page.

Comment: The number is the id of different movies. That's why you got different comments. If you go the main movie page http://movie.douban.com/subject/2303845/, you will see that it is the same as http://movie.douban.com/subject/2303845/?from=showing/comments.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that is what you wanted as when I type in your original URL of http://movie.douban.com/subject/2303845/comments it redirects to http://movie.douban.com.  I thought that was your problem.  What you are saying is that http://movie.douban.com/subject/2303845/comments is different than http://movie.douban.com/subject/2303845/?from=showing/comments?  If so can you specify how to get to http://movie.douban.com/subject/2303845/comments?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My problem is that I would like to get the data from  movie.douban.com/subject/2303845/comments. However, when I ran my script, it detected that the request got redirected back to the main movie page movie.douban.com/subject/2303845/. Hence I was unable to get the data I want from the original page. I cannot figure out a way to stay on movie.douban.com/subject/2303845/comments page to scrape the data.

Comment: How do you navigate to movie.douban.com/subject/2303845/comments from movie.douban.com/subject/2303845/  ?

Comment: In my code, I just add "comments" in the end of the link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92786/discussion-between-dstudeba-and-yal).